# Collate logs from multiple springboot instances on different machines

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, logback, spring-logback

I have a springboot application which is running on multiple nodes for load balancing. Each springboot instance generates its own log in the filesystem. To investigate the logs, i need to manually look through the different log files in different machines.

I am looking for an utility that will collate the logs as a single file or may be expose some HTML ui for looking at the log messages.

I expect the tool to be lightweight without db access. The tool will be hosted in one of the machine where springboot is running.

The environment is linux and I am using slf4j with logback.

Answer (score 1):

You should look at [ELK Logging](https://www.elastic.co/log-monitoring) for a comprehensive solution.

If that is a step too far look at using a Logback Database [apender](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html) and write the logs to a database, then pull them back with [Spring Data Rest](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-rest/) API.